# [xpath]get siblings until class appears

Tags: xpath

```
<div>
    <div class="header">
        <p>name 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">czx</div>
    <div class="content">dsczx</div>
    <div class="content">czsadx</div>
    <div class="content">cz34x</div>
    <div class="content">4czewtwex</div>
    <div class="header">
        <p>name 2</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">czx</div>
    <div class="content">czsadx</div>
    <div class="content">cz34x</div>
    <div class="content">4czewtwex</div>
    <div class="header">
        <p>name 3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">czx</div>
    <div class="content">czsadx</div>
    <div class="content">cz34x</div>
    <div class="content">4czewtwex</div>
</div>
```

Hi folks!
I've got a problematic structure like that. I'd like to create an xpath which will get all `<div>` elements below given `<p>` which got class 'content', BUT if there's any other element with class 'header', elements below 'header' will be omitted.

```
//div/p[text() = 'name 1']/../following-sibling::div[@class = 'content']
```

for `//div/p[text() = 'name 1']/../following-sibling::div[@class = 'content']` output should be:

```
<div class="content">czx</div>
<div class="content">dsczx</div>
<div class="content">czsadx</div>
<div class="content">cz34x</div>
<div class="content">4czewtwex</div>
```

for `//div/p[text() = 'name 2']/../following-sibling::div[@class = 'content']` output should be:

```
<div class="content">czx</div>
<div class="content">czsadx</div>
<div class="content">cz34x</div>
<div class="content">4czewtwex</div>
```

for `//div/p[text() = 'name 3']/../following-sibling::div[@class = 'content']` output should be:

```
<div class="content">czx</div>
<div class="content">czsadx</div>
<div class="content">cz34x</div>
<div class="content">4czewtwex</div>
```

Comment: Could you please show what output you expect for 'name 1'?

Answer (score 0):

It's little bit complicated (I'm sure it is possible to do it more nice). Notice 'name X' is used in 3 places (you will need to replace it as well 3 times).

1. Take all elements from bottom to 'name 3'

> /div/div[preceding-sibling::div/p='name 3']

2. Give total number of elements in our sub list

> count(/div/div[preceding-sibling::div/p='name 3'])

3. Return first position of DIV with class Header, if none found, it returns 0.

> count(/div/div[preceding-sibling::div/p='name
>   3'][@class='header']/following::div)

4. Now we have a list, total amount of elements into it, and position of first DIV with class Header (or 0 otherwise). Now we can count how many position we really need

> total amount of our sublist minus number of elements we want to delete
>   from list.

**xPath (wokring solution):**

```
/div/div[preceding-sibling::div/p='name 3'][position()<count(/div/div[preceding-sibling::div/p='name 3'])+1-count(/div/div[preceding-sibling::div/p='name 3'][@class='header']/following::div)][@class='content']
```

Comment: Not exactly. I don't know how many elements with class 'header' could be and in 'p' tag could be random text.

Comment: Could you please show an example which would not pass this solution?

Comment: It does not match if we have only one 'div class="header"' (and some 'div class="content"'), or we are trying to get last section which does not ended with 'p'.

Comment: @JohnTravis I think I've made it. Check out new solution.